# Function for constructing URL from Next.js dynamic route (with `[slug]`)

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

This feels gross to me. Is there a better way to implement `getUrlFromRouteWithSlug`?

Does Next.js offer a function for it?

```TypeScript
const TEACHER = "/teacher";
export const TEACHER_PROFILE = `${TEACHER}/profile`;
export const TEACHER_PROFILE_BY_TEACHEROF_ID = `${TEACHER_PROFILE}/[teacherOfId]`;

/**
 * E.g. Inputs 'exampleString[slug]', 'exampleString[secondSlug]', and 'exampleString' all return 'exampleString' if replaceValue is ''.
 */
function replaceTrailingSquareBracketsChunk(
  inputString: string,
  replaceValue: string
): string {
  const regex = /\[[^\]]*\]$/; // Matches text in square brackets at the end of the string. See test cases.
  return inputString.replace(regex, replaceValue);
}

function getUrlFromRouteWithSlug(route: string, slug: string): string {
  const href = `${BASE_URL}${replaceTrailingSquareBracketsChunk(route, "")}${slug}`;
  return href;
}

const url = getUrlFromRouteWithSlug(TEACHER_PROFILE_BY_TEACHEROF_ID, 'fkjhk435')
```

I couldn't find it at https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes or https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/dynamic-routes/dynamic-routes-details

Elsewhere in our app, we rely on route definitions, such as:

```TypeScript
if (router.route === TEACHER_PROFILE_BY_TEACHEROF_ID) {
  //...
}
```

So we need a clean way of building an URL via that route and its ingredients, which in this case is a single slug (`teacherOfId`).

And the TEACHER_PROFILE_BY_TEACHEROF_ID route needs to be treated as distinct from the TEACHER_PROFILE route.

Comment: Are you trying to extract id from URL ? Please add more details to the question like you using App Router or Pages Router ? Expected output ?

Comment: @Beast80K Thanks for your questions. I reworded my question above. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So you basically want to `/teacher/profile/[teacherOfId]` ---> `/teacher/profile/fkjhk435`  ?

Comment: Yes, and ideally it should be able to handle more complicated Next.js dynamic routes too, as described at https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments See my next update to my question too for another clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to create const teacherSlug = '[teacherOfId]' and use teacherSlug to replace string instead of using regex ?

Comment: @Kiran Yep, that would work. I'd just need to create a `const` for every dynamic slug. I'd rather have just one function handle it all, if possible.